# Best way to get value from another observable without combineLatest

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I have 2 observables in which are basically 2 dom events. one is a 'dragstart' event and the other is 'drop' event.
Obviously the dragStart will start first, and hold the variable until the dropEvent Observable fires.

here's a quick example which will help clarify:

```
this.containerEl = document.querySelector...

var dragStart$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.containerEl, 'dragstart')
        .map((e) => e.target)

var dropEvent$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.containerEl, 'drop')
        .map((e) => e.target)

var subscription = dropEvent$.subscribe( (el) =>{
  el.appendChild( **NEED DRAGSTART EL HERE** )
})
```

I tried using combineLatest(dragStart$,dropEvent$) on the subscription but that obviously won't work because dragStart$ will fire before dropEvent$.

**NOTE**

My GOAL is to **NOT** USE external state on this. IE: set a global var on the dragStart$ and just accessing on the dropEvent$.

What is a good solution for this?  Im sorta learning rxJS right now so any expert opinion would be appreciated!

Comment: maybe `withLatestFrom`? For instance `dragStart$.withLatestFrom(dropEvent$)` Or the other way around, not sure what you want.

Comment: that was it thank you!  im trying to learn  all of these operators and must have missed this one : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know drop events must follow dragStart events, the best way is to model the drag/drop sequence as a single observable.  Only start observing the drop event after you receive a start event:

```
// observes start events
const start$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.containerEl, 'dragstart');
// will observe the *next* drop event
const nextDrop$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.containerEl, 'drop').take(1);

const dragDrop$ = start$
    // for each start event, listen for next drop event
    .flatMap({target: startEl} => nextDrop$
        // for drop event, return the start and end elements
        .map({target: endEl} => ({startEl, endEl})));

const subscription = dragDrop$.subscribe(({startEl, endEl}) => {
    endEl.appendChild(startEl);
});
```

Comment: Thanks ! This worked, but I had to use concatMap instead of flatMap as the latest rxJS does not have this operator anymore. they must have taken it out ??

Answer (score 0):

This is right from the examples from Rxjs and is a perfect solution.  It uses .takeUntil(mouseup_event) because when you mouse up you are done.  No external state

```
var dragTarget = document.getElementById('dragTarget');

// Get the three major events
var mouseup   = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(dragTarget, 'mouseup');
var mousemove = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document,   'mousemove');
var mousedown = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(dragTarget, 'mousedown');

var mousedrag = mousedown.flatMap(function (md) {

  // calculate offsets when mouse down
  var startX = md.offsetX, startY = md.offsetY;

  // Calculate delta with mousemove until mouseup
  return mousemove.map(function (mm) {
    mm.preventDefault();

    return {
      left: mm.clientX - startX,
      top: mm.clientY - startY
    };
  }).takeUntil(mouseup);
});

// Update position
var subscription = mousedrag.subscribe(function (pos) {
  dragTarget.style.top = pos.top + 'px';
  dragTarget.style.left = pos.left + 'px';
});
```